# Why onomasiological studies are less popular/frequent than semasiological ones?

Tags: computational-linguistics, language-change

When searching for research on semantic shift, it becomes apparent that the majority of studies concentrate on the semasiological perspective—how a word's meaning evolves over time. In contrast, the onomasiological approach, which investigates how different words are used to represent the same concept across time, appears to be addressed in fewer articles.

Is there a practical explanation for this disparity in research focus? Are there factors that contribute to the relatively lower attention given to the onomasiological aspect of language change in comparison to the semasiological aspect? I'm curious to understand the potential reasons behind this trend.

Comment: Because when dealing with abstractions, we can't tell whether they "represent the same concept across time" or not. The ancients had some funny ideas, and they often confused words with them. On the other hand, you may get some use out of Buck's _A Dictionary of Selected Synonyms in the Principal Indo-European Languages_, which covers an entire ontology.